# HTML Form won't send email on submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I've developed an iOS app and rails backend server. While I took some HTML classes back in university, it's been a long while since I've touched any.

I purchased a 'template' website to be my application landing page. I've tweaked it to be what I want, but I'm having 1 issue with the Contact/Form Submission page. When I press send, I do not receive an email at the intended email address. I'm not sure if this is an issue with the code (I'm guessing not, I would think this highly rated template would have had something like this correct), or if I need to set up something with my domain that I currently haven't done as I wouldn't know about it.

Here's the relevant code...

index.html

```
<form action="javascript:;" method="post">
    ...
    <input type="submit" class="button white" value="Send &#x2192;" />
</form>
```

send_email.php

```
<?php

    // Replace this with your own email address
    $to="example@gmail.com";

    // Extract form contents
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    // Validate email address
    function valid_email($str) {
        return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }

    // Return errors if present
    $errors = "";

    if($name =='') { $errors .= "name,"; }
    if(valid_email($email)==FALSE) { $errors .= "email,"; }
    if($message =='') { $errors .= "message,"; }

    // Send email
    if($errors =='') {

        $headers =  'From: FluidApp <no-reply@fluidapp.com>'. "\r\n" .
                    'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
                    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        $email_subject = "Website Contact Form: $email";
        $message="Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nWebsite: $website \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nMessage:\n\n $message";

        mail($to, $email_subject, $message, $headers);
        echo "true";

    } else {
        echo $errors;
    }

?>
```

However, nothing is being sent to my email "example@gmail.com".

What might I be missing here?

Comment: You say your app is on ruby on rails but your send email code is in php.

Comment: @doru My app is for iOS, aI wrote it's backend server in rails. However, I purchased a "landing page" website template (this one to be exact http://themeforest.net/item/fluidapp-responsive-mobile-app-website-template/2251839), which is written in HTML, CSS, PHP. I'm just tweaking it to show my images, etc. I didn't want to write a site from scratch. My apps server and this landing page are 2 different things. Probably shouldn't have even mentioned my app or backend.

Comment: For debugging see [PHP mail form doesn't complete sending e-mail](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24644436)

Comment: Are you sure there's an SMTP server?

Comment: @vpzomtrrfrt No, I'm not sure. I bought the cheapest option off of namecheap for a domain and hosting. I'm not too familiar with the dashboard right now or where to check, but I'm looking into it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe replace

```
<form action="javascript:;" method="post">
```

with

```
<form action="send_email.php" method="post">
```

That should do it, assuming the `...` in your HTML snippet contains the right variables for the form submission- `name`, `email`, `website`, `subject`, `message`, etc.

**EDIT:** [OP figured it out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234107/html-form-wont-send-email-on-submit/31234129#comment50469409_31234129)

Comment: Yeah, they contain the right variables. After replacing that with "send_email.php", upon pressing "Send" I'm taken to myexamplewebsite.com/send_email.php and the page just reads "true" from the echo statement in php. However, no email sent after 5 mins of waiting.

Comment: @chrisP Hmm. Maybe take a peek at this line: `$to="example@gmail.com";` ?

Comment: It seems to be good. I've quintuple verified the address I have in there is my email address.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to configure anything on my website domain management, or hosting management? I bought the cheapest hosting and domain I could off of namecheap yesterday. Is there some configuration I might be missing?

Comment: @chrisP I tested your code and it seems to be running fine. However, I ran it on localhost, which means that I won't be able to get emails either. I think the problem lies somewhere in your server setup- can you tell me if you are hosting the website locally or remotely? Let's continue our discussion in a chat room [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82427/chat-for-blue-ice-and-chris-p)- it'll be easier instead of using comments. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try a library designed for this purpose such as PHPMailer instead of using PHP's mail function. It makes my life easier.

Comment: Got it. Needed to add the from email. Whoops.

Comment: @chrisP, I'm adding a link to your comment in my answer. If you wish, you can mark my answer with the checkmark if you feel like it helped.

Answer (score -1):

Place the `<form action="send_email.php" method="post">`

and remove `<form action="javascript:;" method="post">`

it will work perfect your send_email.php is good

place all 2 files in same folder

Comment: Stay original, my friend :)